# How to send a byteArray to Worker class when implementing WorkManger?

Tags: android, arrays, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I am trying to send a byteArray as an input data to my Worker Class inside the WorkRequest. Is there a way to send byteArray and receive the same inside the worker class?

I have tried to send IntArray and I am able to achieve the result.

Implementation:

```
//work request
 val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWroker::class.java)
                  .setInputData(createInputData())
                  .build()
//create Input Data for work request
fun createInputData(): Data {
        return Data.Builder()
                .putString(FIRST_KEY, "My value")
                .putInt(SECOND_KEY, 5)
                .putByteArray(getByteArray())
                .build()
    }

I am getting an error cannot resolve method getByteArray(). I have read the documentation of Data class and there is no such method available.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support to store and retrieve bytes and byte arrays into `Data` object has been added to [WorkManager v2.1.0-alpha01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#2.1.0-alpha01).

You can add WorkManager's KTX and use [`OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<>()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/package-summary#onetimeworkrequestbuilder) and [`workDataOf()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/package-summary#workdataof) in your work request (or use the `putByteArray()` method of the `Data.Builder` object):

```
val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<MyWorker>()
    .setInputData(createInputData())
    .build()

private fun createInputData() = workDataOf(
    FIRST_KEY to "My value", 
    SECOND_KEY to byteArrayOf(0x2E, 0x38))
```

and then retrieve the byte array in your worker using something like:

```
class MyWorker(ctx: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(ctx, params) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        val myByteArray = inputData.getByteArray()

        // Do something with the ByteArray

        Result.success()
    }
}
```